# 15.04 Can only boot with upstart, systemd boot fails

Tags: boot, 15.04, upstart, systemd

If I try a normal boot into 15.04, I get thrown into a command line-only session with some disks marked read-only.  I can boot fine with upstart.  The tail end of dmesg when I boot under systemd is:

```
[  102.349981] sky2 0000:06:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[  132.566670] gpu-manager[1651]: segfault at c0 ip 00007f7135baac44 sp 00007ffe19d39f40 error 4 in libc-2.21.so[7f7135b61000+1c0000]
[  157.046137] gpu-manager[1822]: segfault at c0 ip 00007f21f0bb4c44 sp 00007fffdd186650 error 4 in libc-2.21.so[7f21f0b6b000+1c0000]
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on what's causing this/how to fix it